# Density of levels in Fermi-Dirac statistics

Tags: solid-state-physics, fermions, fermi-energy

We know that
$$
u=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} D(\mathcal{E})\mathcal{E}f(\mathcal{E})d\mathcal{E}
$$
where $D(\mathcal{E})$ is called *density of levels* per unit volume.
My textbook (Kittel) says that:

- $D(\mathcal{E})$ is the density of single-particle states as function of energy
- $f(\mathcal{E})D(\mathcal{E})$ is the density of filled orbitals

I don't understand the difference.
And orbital and single.particle state are the same thing? 
Each orbital is defined by all the quantum numbers and only one electron can occupy it. So the density of energy state D(E) is the number of suitable orbitals in that range of energy?

Comment: $D$ is the density of levels, whether or not they are occupied.  $f$ is the probability that a level is occupied.  Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

> orbital and single.particle state are the same thing?

A part for a factor $2$, due to the spin degeneracy, yes they are the same thing.

The difference between $D(\mathcal{E})$ and $f(\mathcal{E})D(\mathcal{E})$ is entirely in the adjective *filled*.

The density of states is a purely mechanic concept depending only on the spectrum of the eigenvalues. Instead, physical properties depend heavily on how the available states are occupied. Which is, in turn, a function of the temperature of the system.

Comment: Ok. I totally missed the adjective _filled_.

Comment: but, searching better in the textbook, I found this: "Strictly, D(E) is the density of one-particle states, or density of orbitals". So, at least in the textbook, orbital and single-particle state are the same

Comment: What do you think? Do you agree?

Comment: @JBach  I agree. Orbital = wavefunction solution of Schroedinger equation = one particle state (actually two-particle, taking into account the spin). Of course, the filling of such orbitals/states is a different story. The state may be filled or empty, depending on how many electrons are thee in total and on the precise external conditions.